# App Engine query ignores batch_size according to appstats?

Tags: google-app-engine

I´m running a query with a batch size of 1000

```
self.model.all().run(batch_size=1000)
```

Yet, in app stats, the query is listed with multiple reads with a batch size of 300:

```
@68ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=48ms api=0ms cost=21070 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:301]
@338ms datastore_v3.Next real=217ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@851ms datastore_v3.Next real=193ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@1323ms datastore_v3.Next real=128ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@1739ms datastore_v3.Next real=200ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@2214ms datastore_v3.Next real=139ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@2641ms datastore_v3.Next real=199ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@3121ms datastore_v3.Next real=210ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@3628ms datastore_v3.Next real=198ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@4149ms datastore_v3.Next real=202ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@4724ms datastore_v3.Next real=203ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@5222ms datastore_v3.Next real=202ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@5652ms datastore_v3.Next real=266ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@6139ms datastore_v3.Next real=196ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
@6627ms datastore_v3.Next real=202ms api=0ms cost=21000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_READ:300]
```

The amount of batched matched up with a batch size of 300.

Why is the batch_size setting being ignored?

Comment: Using a batch_size=10 to cripple it to a halt works though ;)... So the argument is used. Strange.

Comment: Looking in the code the following comments are made 

`batch_size: int, hint for the number of results returned per RPC`
`prefetch_size: int, hint for the number of results in the first RPC` I can't see anything explicity limiting the batchsize to 300, but haven't looked down to the next layer of code in `datastore_query`

Comment: Remember any result set from a batch has to be less than 1MB, so something may kick in to limit result sizes.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that might be it. The Entites total size in "Datastore Statistics" is 2BM (4,418 items) and 9MB for the indexes. Entites Size should be the relevant one though?! If it is, that should not be limiting...